# ng-click event is not working in ionic, but it works in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created a input clear directive to clear `input` field, but its not working in ionic, `ng-click` event is not firing, same code is working fine in angular fiddle.

[Here is angular demo](http://jsbin.com/cekilecusi/edit?html,js,output)

[Here is ionic demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxBjOg?editors=0010)

My template in ionic look like this

```
<ion-list>
   <label class="item item-input" input-clear >
      <input type="text" 
         ng-model="user.email" 
         placeholder="{{ 'LOGIN.EMAIL_ID' | translate }}">
   </label>
</ion-list>
```

and very simple controller

```
.controller('forgotPasswordCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {};
});
```

**update**

directive

```
.directive('inputClear', function($compile) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
    // Find the input and bind keyup
    var input = element.find("input");

    // Input length
    scope.input = { len : 0 };

    scope.clearInput = function () {
        input[0].value = "";
        console.log(input);
    };

    input.bind("keyup", function() {
      scope.input.len = input[0].value.length;
      if(scope.input.len > 1) {
        console.log(scope.input.len);  
      }
      scope.$apply();
    });

    var el = angular.element('<a class="clear-text button-clear" ng-show="input.len > 1" ng-click="clearInput()">X</a>');
    $compile(el)(scope);
    element.append(el);
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: Do you have dependency to `angular-touch.js` module?

Comment: i don't have it in `app.js` dep list, maybe its included in ionic bundle, but I have tried using `ng-touch` instead `ng-click`, same issue, not firing

Comment: You'ev got a link to the demo; but your actual directive code should be in the question too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work in ionic is because you have the input-clear directive on a label which is blocking the click from firing. By changing the label element to a div it starts working again.

[Heres the codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgqQVP)

```
<ion-list>
  <div class="item item-input" input-clear>
    <input type="email" required ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Email Id">
  </div>
</ion-list>
```

Here's a similar problem that was solved in the same way https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/buttons-inside-form-labels/29033

Answer (score 0):

For the **form** tag you need to add

```
novalidate=""
```

then the message will be fired . here is a working [code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyzJxG?editors=1010)